# Android - Back button causes problems

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-spinner

I am trying to create an app that keeps track of the countries the user has visited. A country is selected from a drop down spinner and then a number is entered into a text field. The next screen should show the top three countries visited in order of frequency.

The first time you enter a country and frequency it works fine but the problem arises when you press the back button and then select a different country and enter another frequency, it does not assign the frequency to the correct country.

To give an example, if you first select Austria and Times Visited as 5 and the press next it shows:

```
Austria       5
Wales         0
Switzerland   0
```

If you press back and then select Belgium and enter 10, it shows

```
Denmark       10
Austria       5
Wales         0
```

If you go back for a third time and select Luxemburg and enter 15, it shows

```
Spain         15
Denmark       10
Austria       5
```

It seems as though the countryList array is becoming out of sync from the spinner position and I am not sure how to fix it, any help would be much appreciated.

This is the first android app I have tried to make so there may be other mistakes of which I am not aware.

Thanks

Here is the first activity:

```
package com.example.country;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.Collections;

public class Select extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView flagChoiceView;
Spinner spinnerCountry;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
public static Button next2;
int elementPosition;

//Declaring all objects of type country
country Austria = new country("Austria");
country Belgium = new country("Belgium");
country Denmark = new country("Denmark");
country England = new country("England");
country France = new country("France");
country Germany = new country("Germany");
country Ireland = new country("Ireland");
country Italy = new country("Italy");
country Luxembourg = new country("Luxembourg");
country Portugal = new country("Portugal");
country Spain = new country("Spain");
country Sweden = new country("Sweden");
country Switzerland = new country("Switzerland");
country Wales = new country("Wales");

//Creating an array of type country in preparation for sorting
country[] countryList = {Austria, Belgium, Denmark,England,France,
        Germany,Ireland,Italy,Luxembourg,Portugal,Spain,Sweden,Switzerland,Wales};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    afterSecondClick();



    //Setting protocols for entering values into the text field
    final TextWatcher numberInput = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try{
                countryList[elementPosition].setFrequency(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                countryList[elementPosition].setFrequency(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    };

    //Creating a listener for the input field
    EditText inputFrequency = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputFrequency);
    inputFrequency.addTextChangedListener(numberInput);

    //sortFunction(countryList);
    spinnerCountry = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dropdown);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.country_list,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            flagChoiceView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flagChoice);

            elementPosition = position;
           switch(position)
           {
               case 0:

                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.austriaflag);
               break;

               case 1:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.belgiumflag);
                   break;

               case 2:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.denmarkflag);
                   break;

               case 3:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.englandflag);
                   break;

               case 4:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.franceflag);
                   break;

               case 5:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.germanflag);
                   break;

               case 6:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.irelandflag);
                   elementPosition = position;
                   break;

               case 7:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.italyflag);
                   break;

               case 8:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.luxembourgeflag);
                   break;

               case 9:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.portugalflag);
                   break;

               case 10:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.spainflag);
                   break;

               case 11:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.swedenflag);
                   break;

               case 12:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.switzerlandflag);
                   break;

               case 13:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.walesflag);
                   break;

               default:
                   flagChoiceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.austriaflag);
                   break;

           }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}

//Linking the second activity to the third with a button click
public void afterSecondClick()
{
    next2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    next2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    sortFunction(countryList);



                    Intent proceedAgain = new Intent("com.example.country.Results");
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("firstCountry", countryList[13].getName());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("secondCountry", countryList[12].getName());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("thirdCountry", countryList[11].getName());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("firstFrequency", countryList[13].getFrequency());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("secondFrequency", countryList[12].getFrequency());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("thirdFrequency", countryList[11].getFrequency());
                    startActivity(proceedAgain);
                    EditText inputFrequency=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFrequency);
                    inputFrequency.setText("");



                }
            }
    );
}

//Declaring a new inner class known as country
private class country
{
    private String name;
    private int frequency;

    public country(String Name){
        this.name = Name;
        this.frequency = 0;
    }

    public country(){
        this.name = "";
        this.frequency = 0;
    }

    public void setFrequency(int freq){
        this.frequency = freq;
    }

    public int getFrequency(){
        return frequency;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

//Sorting algorithm from lowest frequency to highest
void sortFunction(country[] List){
    int count = 0;
    while(count < List.length){
        for(int n = 0; n < List.length - 1; n++){
            if(List[n].getFrequency() > List[n+1].getFrequency())
                swapFunction(List, n);
        }
        count++;
    }
}

//Counterpart Method to sortFunction
void swapFunction(country[] List, int m){
    country a, b, c;
    a = List[m];
    b = List[m+1];
    c = a;
    List[m+1] = c;
    List[m] = b;
}
}
```

and here is the second activity:

```
package com.example.country;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Results extends AppCompatActivity

{
//Inflation of GUI and toolbar for the activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    TextView countryOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstCountry);
    countryOne.setText(extras.getString("firstCountry"));

    TextView countryTwo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondCountry);
    countryTwo.setText(extras.getString("secondCountry"));

    TextView countryThree = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thirdCountry);
    countryThree.setText(extras.getString("thirdCountry"));

    TextView freqOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstFrequency);
    freqOne.setText(String.valueOf(extras.getInt("firstFrequency")));

    TextView freqTwo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondFrequency);
    freqTwo.setText(String.valueOf(extras.getInt("secondFrequency")));

    TextView freqThree = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thirdFrequency);
    freqThree.setText(String.valueOf(extras.getInt("thirdFrequency")));
}

}
```

and the xml of the array is here:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">COUNTry</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="appName">Welcome!</string>
<string name="nextButtonValue">NEXT</string>
<string name="title_activity_select">Select</string>
<string-array name="country_list">
    <item>Austria</item>
    <item>Belgium</item>
    <item>Denmark</item>
    <item>England</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>Germany</item>
    <item>Ireland</item>
    <item>Italy</item>
    <item>Luxembourg</item>
    <item>Portugal</item>
    <item>Spain</item>
    <item>Sweden</item>
    <item>Switzerland</item>
```

Comment: Define "correct country". An example would be more beneficial than a brief description.

Comment: Also, advice. Store the flag with the country. `new country("Austria", R.drawable.austriaflag)`

Comment: Curious, on the second round do you have duplicated entries in your dropdown list?

Comment: Could you provide the code of the array xml?

Comment: Do not vandalise your own post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example above:

The problem is that **elementPosition is 1 when you select Belgium**, but you have sorted the country list, so that **Belgium on the list is on position 0 and not in 1**. So it updates the frequency of the Denmark which is on position 1 (the second in the country list).

To solve this, you should modify the country's frequency if that matches the given country Name (e.g Belgium) and not the country position on the spinner (as the spinner is not sorted and does not match).

So one approach is to search each country in your list, and if it's name matches the spinners selected item's name (country name, check it with .equals()), then update its frequency.

---

Also, your code has another problem, if you **first enter the text value** and **then select the country**, the **update will go to the wrong country**. So you must do whatever you do (the **update of the frequency**) on the EditText in your **onClick method of the button**.

---

So, the solution code would be something like that:

Inside afterSecondClick method -> inside the onClick method -> in your R.id.button Button:

**Before the sorting!!!** (Before this line: `sortFunction(countryList);`)

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFrequency);


Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dropdown);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


int count = 0;
while(count < countryList.length)
{
    if((countryList[count]).getName().equals(text))
    {
        try
        {
            countryList[count].setFrequency(Integer.parseInt(ed.toString()));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            countryList[count].setFrequency(0);
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

Which has time complexitiy O(n). Your sorting algorithm has time complexity O(n^2) so it does not affect much the speed. Furthermore, for a few countries (around 100) it can be considered fast. Also try to use Quicksort for your sorting algorithm for speed (but still for small number of countries it is ok as you have it right now)

And also **remove the TextWatcher** from the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
package com.example.country;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Select extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView flagChoiceView;
Spinner spinnerCountry;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
public static Button next2;

//Declaring all objects of type Country
List<Country> countries = Arrays.asList(
        new Country("Austria", R.drawable.austriaflag),
        new Country("Belgium", R.drawable.belgiumflag),
        new Country("Denmark", R.drawable.denmarkflag),
        new Country("England", R.drawable.englandflag),
        new Country("France", R.drawable.franceflag),
        new Country("Germany", R.drawable.germanflag),
        new Country("Ireland", R.drawable.irelandflag),
        new Country("Italy", R.drawable.italyflag),
        new Country("Luxembourg", R.drawable.luxembourgeflag),
        new Country("Portugal", R.drawable.portugalflag),
        new Country("Spain", R.drawable.spainflag),
        new Country("Sweden", R.drawable.swedenflag),
        new Country("Switzerland", R.drawable.switzerlandflag),
        new Country("Wales", R.drawable.walesflag)
);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    afterSecondClick();

    //Setting protocols for entering values into the text field
    final TextWatcher numberInput = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                countries.get(spinnerCountry.getSelectedItemPosition()).setFrequency(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getParent(), s + " is not a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };

    //Creating a listener for the input field
    EditText inputFrequency = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFrequency);
    inputFrequency.addTextChangedListener(numberInput);

    //sortFunction(countryList);
    spinnerCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dropdown);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            flagChoiceView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flagChoice);
            flagChoiceView.setImageResource(countries.get(position).getFlag());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

}

//Linking the second activity to the third with a button click
public void afterSecondClick() {
    next2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    next2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Collections.sort(countries, Country.sortByFrequency());
                    Intent proceedAgain = new Intent("com.example.Country.Results");
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("firstCountry", countries.get(countries.size() - 1).getName());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("secondCountry", countries.get(countries.size() - 2).getName());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("thirdCountry", countries.get(countries.size() - 3).getName());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("firstFrequency", countries.get(countries.size() - 1).getFrequency());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("secondFrequency", countries.get(countries.size() - 2).getFrequency());
                    proceedAgain.putExtra("thirdFrequency", countries.get(countries.size() - 3).getFrequency());
                    startActivity(proceedAgain);
                    EditText inputFrequency = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFrequency);
                    inputFrequency.setText("");
                }
            }
    );
}

//Declaring a new inner class known as Country
private static class Country {
    private final String name;
    private int frequency;
    private final int flag;

    public Country(String Name, int flag) {
        this.name = Name;
        this.frequency = 0;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public void setFrequency(int freq) {
        this.frequency = freq;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public static Comparator<Country> sortByFrequency() {
        return new Comparator<Country>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Country lhs, Country rhs) {
                return Integer.compare(lhs.getFrequency(), rhs.getFrequency());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just you will be Add in MainActivity.java file Add this

```
@Override
public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```